# ETS or ARIMA model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing

I have a time series data set and want to predict my data in the future. I would like to when to use a ETS or an ARIMA model?

Is is true that you can only use a ETS model when a data is non-stationary? And when a data is stationary you need to difference it first and then use an ARIMA model to make some forecasting?

I am doing the forecasting in r.

Comment: ETS works both for stationary and nonstationary data.

Comment: So how do you know which model to use? When to use ETS and when ARIMA?

Comment: It is an empirical question. Also, ARIMA and ETS overlap. An ARIMA model can often be formulated as ETS and vice versa.

Comment: The second question is also not true.